c++ default constructor can't build an object
c++ default constructor can't build an object.
class Data {

};

int main() {

    Data data();    // this way can't build data. 
    
    Data data1{};

    Data data2;
}

Data data(); can't step in Data default constructor.
i want to know what happended. thanks.

Data data(); declares a function called data which takes zero arguments. To default construct an object you want Data data;

Look up "most vexing parse".   Data data() is not creating an object named data.  It is declaring a function named data() which accepts no arguments and returns a Data.     Do Data data instead to create an object data using the default constructor (with no arguments).

See Why can't the default constructor be called with empty brackets?

@Peter -- if you look up most vexing parse you won't find this one. It's not "vexing"; once past the beginner stage it's easily recognized as a function declaration. The most vexing parse describes more complex declarations which are truly vexing.

thank you all. i understand it. but i have a new question now.
data is not allowed to be implemented here in c++, so why are declarations still permitted？
